# How to append two streams?

Tags: scheme

I have got these functions

```
(define force!
  (lambda (thunk)
    (thunk)))


(define stream-head
  (lambda (s n)
    (if (zero? n)
        '()
        (cons (car s)
              (stream-head (force! (cdr s))
                           (1- n))))))

(define make-stream
  (lambda (seed next)
    (letrec ([produce (lambda (current)
                        (cons current
                              (lambda ()
                                (produce (next current)))))])
      (produce seed))))



(define make-traced-stream
  (lambda (seed next)
    (letrec ([produce (trace-lambda produce (current)
                        (cons current
                              (lambda ()
                                (produce (next current)))))])
      (produce seed))))

(define stream-of-even-natural-numbers
  (make-traced-stream 0
                      (lambda (n)
                        (+ n 2))))

(define stream-of-odd-natural-numbers
  (make-traced-stream 1
                      (lambda (n)
                        (+ n 2))))
```

And I need to make a function that appends the last two streams, so that if I run

```
(stream-head (append-stream stream-of-even-natural-numbers stream-of-odd-natural-numbers) 4)

I get the output (0 2 1 3)
```

Problem is, that the streams are infinite, and I dunno how to make a function that knows when to stop taking input from the first stream and then continue taking input from the last.

Earlier I made the Merge of the two lists, which looks like this;

```
>  (define (merge-streams s1 s2)  (cons (car s1)  (delay (merge-streams
> s2 (force!(cdr s1))))))

(stream-head (merge-stream stream-of-even-natural-numbers stream-of-odd-natural-numbers) 10)
= (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Here I can delay, and alternate which element from each list that I take.

How can I make a smart procedure to append the lists?

Comment: a side note: `stream-head` has a bug - it forces one too many elements in the stream, which can cause an error, needlessly. No need to force the tail if `n==1`, just take the `car` of it, it's already there.

Comment: your example of `(0 2 1 3)` is not enough to disambiguate the appending from the merging, to glean your meaning. did you intend for `(head (append ...) 6)` to return `(0 2 4 1 3 5)` and `(head (append ...) 8)` to return `(0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7)`? if so, it looks like it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (append-streams s1 s2)
  (cond
    [(empty-stream? s1) s2] 
    [(empty-stream? s2) s1]
    [else 
     (cons (stream-car s1) 
           (delay (append-streams (stream-cdr s1) s2)))]))
```

Comment: except that no `empty-stream?` definition is shown in the question.

Comment: An explicit statement of how the stream is represented would be nice too. In the question thunks are used, but in the previous stream question `delay` was used.

Comment: from what's posted, looks like these streams can only be infinite... perhaps the posting is incomplete...

Comment: If so we can write `(define (append-streams s1 s2) s1)`. But I think you are right, there might be missing something.

Comment: exactly! in fact, I'm typing that answer right now!! :) don't know if I'll post it though...

Answer (score 1):

From what you show, the streams can only be infinite. Appending two infinite streams is simple:

```
(define append-infinite-streams
  (lambda (s1 s2)
    s1))
```

If you wanted to have an adaptable appending, reporting back different things depending on how it is called through `stream-head`, then it is impossible with this set of functions and how they are defining the concept of streams.

And even if you manage to achieve that with some other scheme, this is ill-advised. Shouldn't the shorter prefix of a stream always be part of a longer prefix of the same stream?  But you seem to want

```
(define s3 (stream-append s1 s2))

(stream-head s3 6) 
=> (0 2 4 1 3 5) 

(stream-head s3 8) 
=> (0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7)
```